# How to make the list empty after returning from function/class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's imagine. We have the following 2 classes,
`class ONE` just returns the output list produced by `class TWO`. The problem here is I want to clear/empty the `final_issues` list once's `class ONE` returns the list so that it won't output the duplicate entries on the second round.

```
final_issues = []

class ONE:
    def out(self):
        if final_issues:
            return final_issues
            ###! HERE i want to make `final_issues` empty

class TWO:
    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(5):
            final_issues.append(i)
```

`First Iteration:`

```
TWO()
final_issues
>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
x = ONE()
x.out()
>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`Second Iteration`

```
TWO()
final_issues 
>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
x = ONE()
x.out()
>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to clear the list after each iteration of `TWO()` class so that it won't append the result to previous `final_issues` list

Please Note: `final_issues` doesn't contain the integers on My Real Problem (IT IS UNIQUE VALUE every time), for the demonstration purpose I used integers as an example.

Comment: What do you mean by "after `ONE` returns the list"? Presumably, there must be some delay between returning and clearing it, otherwise a caller could not make use of it, so the question is: How long after?

Comment: Just set `final_issues = []`. Am I missing something?

Comment: A function can't really do anything *after* it returns. So you may need to copy the list, delete the original contents, and return the copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this, copying your list with `final_issues_copy = final_issues[:]` to return it later, and then `clear()`ing the original list (Python 3 only - for Python 2 you could use `del final_issues[:]` instead of `final_issues.clear()`):

```
class ONE:
    def out(self):
        if final_issues:
            print(final_issues)
            final_issues_copy = final_issues[:]
            final_issues.clear()
            return final_issues_copy
```

However (and I understand this is just an example and not your actual code), I would generally caution against manipulating "global" variables like this across classes.